# error=2, No such file or directory when I execute shell in hue4.2 by oozie

Tags: oozie, hue

I'm newer to hue and oozie, when I run a shell job in hue4.2,it told me 

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test.sh" (in directory "/data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1535946784770_0001/container_e29_1535946784770_0001_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory`

I have try to deal with it by edit core-site.xml with proxy or others,but it's useless.

anyone can give me a hand please?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is because the test.sh is not added a "File" in the Shell action. There is a jira to make it automatic with https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-7698

Comment: thanks Romain,but I change  hue version ti 4.3,and  the problem is existing too.

Comment: And when i  change a script from  /user/root/test.sh to hdfs://mycluster/user/root/test.sh it works. Could you tell me why.

Comment: And this is no buttom to added a "File",whether I choose a wrong version for hue?

Comment: File is the 'Files +' on the top right, e.g. http://gethue.com/use-the-shell-action-in-oozie/

Comment: we finally design a new program to replace hue,thank you anyaway